# SSE2 and inline assembly insert structur

Tags: c, gcc, simd, inline-assembly, sse2

I have started to learn SIMD commmands using mixture of c code and gcc inline assembly. I'm trying to understand how could I add values from structure to floating pointer(xmm0). I cannot figure out, what is the proper way to do that.

I have dynamically allocated one structure and named it tmp. Now I want the values of struct to add to the floating pointer using only SSE2 instructions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test{
  unsigned char a;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char c;
  unsigned char d;
} test;

int main()
{
  struct Test *tmp = malloc(sizeof(test));
  tmp->a = 10;
  tmp->b = 2;
  tmp->c = 3;
  tmp->d = 4;
  asm ( "movapd [tmp], %%xmm0;"
  );
  free(tmp);
  return 0;
}
```

After I compile this code I become error message : 
" Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 1 `[tmp]' "

I would like to know what am I doing wrong and how to insert the values of structure in the floating pointer.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Intel intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide) that can be used instead of inline assembly?

Comment: Yes, but I want to learn the proper way to do this with gcc inline assembly

Comment: @BiggyPoopa: I suggest you do it with intrinsics first, then look at the generated code, and then use this as a template for your own inline asm (if you really feel you need to).

Comment: Intrinsics *are* the proper way, as they work on all major x86 compilers and are far more readable than assembly, and are more open to compiler optimizations, and so on.

Comment: I'm with the others about [not using inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm), but if you must, try `asm ( "movapd (%0), %%xmm0;" : : "r"(tmp) : "xmm0" );`.  This is the at&t syntax that gcc uses by default (see also `-masm=intel`).  It also uses gcc's [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) constraints to provide parameters.

Comment: Yes @DavidWohlferd this way works. Thank's a lot.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: except that's not safe.  You forgot [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)

Comment: @Biggy: If you're only still learning about SIMD instructions in the first place, I don't see why you'd want to introduce the complexity of learning how to use GNU C inline asm syntax properly + safely at the same time.  It's hard enough on its own once you understand x86 asm, and how compilers work. And even experts make inline asm mistakes that can lead to confusing hard-to-debug problems unrelated to SIMD mistakes.  If you want to learn SIMD asm, look at the compiler's asm *output* when you use SIMD intrinsics.  And/or hand-write whole functions in asm, starting from compiler output.

Comment: See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sizeof(Test) == 4. That's not going to play nicely with movapd! Also be aware that calls to malloc don't always return 16byte aligned memory, so you probably want to be using _mm_malloc (or equivalent).

Adding to the previous comments, either use intrinsics *(and throw the code into godbolt to see the resulting ASM/machine code)*, or write the entire method in ASM. Besides being about as readable as a newspaper at 100 feet, inline ASM is not portable between compilers, and simply not allowed on some compilers (e.g. VC++). Intrinsics are the preferred option.

Comment: In C you can use `aligned_alloc` to allocate aligned storage.  It's compatible with `free`, unlike `_mm_malloc`.